# Advanced options concatenation in buildroot package .mk file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, buildroot

I'm creating a buildroot package for xmms2 which uses waf build system.
For the configuration step I need to pass the parameters based on the config selection. Actually it's one parameter which has comma separated values. It should look like this:

```
--with-optionals medialib-updater,s4
```

I don't see the way to generate that value. Here is what tried:

```
################################################################################
#
# xmms2
#
################################################################################

XMMS2_VERSION = c081011ddc280908678709d1e80f7ec57efa7b82
XMMS2_SITE = https://github.com/Gamadril/xmms2-devel
XMMS2_SITE_METHOD = git
XMMS2_GIT_SUBMODULES = YES

XMMS2_LICENSE = LGPL-2.1
XMMS2_LICENSE_FILES = COPYING

XMMS2_INSTALL_STAGING = YES

XMMS2_CONF_OPTS = --with-optionals medialib-updater 

ifeq ($(BR2_PACKAGE_XMMS2_DB_S4),y)
XMMS2_CONF_OPTS += ,s4 
endif

$(eval $(waf-package))
```

The result is: `--with-optionals medialib-updater ,s4` - with a space between.
How to get rid of that space? So actually how to concatenate some strings with a separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **make**, the `+=` operator always adds a space. You can append without space by using expansion:

```
XMMS2_CONF_OPTS := "$(XMMS2_CONF_OPTS),s4"
```

Comment: Thanks, tried it but got an error: `*** Recursive variable 'XMMS2_CONF_OPTS' references itself (eventually). Stop.`

Comment: I guess it should be `XMMS2_CONF_OPTS := $(XMMS2_CONF_OPTS),s4`

Comment: You're right, it should be `=` or `:=`. Fixed that in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: with `=` I get the same self-reference-error, with `:=` it works